# Add code to Wordpress site page

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I have this code, attached in JsFiddle and am wondering how i would add it to a single wordpress page? I have tried a few plugins but they just seem to mess up the formatting and stop the javascript from working. Any help would be greatly appreciated. There is a lot of code so i have only added a small snippet here.

```
<div id="top">  
    <div class= "toptext">  
        <span>Bet Type</span>
        <select id = "typeoption"> 
            <option value="0">Qualifying Bet</option> 
        </select>
    </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yLqwthyr/1/

Comment: What (kind of) page? You can easily insert it into the template file.

Comment: is it template or wp admin dashboard page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify your jquery code to run your script in noConflict mode.

If you plan to add a single js file, you need to enqueue it with wp_enqueue_script().

A possible way to do this, assuming you want to add your form structure to a page (with an ID and permalink)

```
 add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'se_40975160');

 function se_40975160(){
      if(is_page('your-page')){
           wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
           wp_register_script('form-js', PATHTOJS . '/js/your-js.js', array('jquery'));

      }
 }
```

For the jQuery script: When you enqueue script that is dependent on jQuery, note that the jQuery in WordPress runs in noConflict mode, which means you cannot use the common $ alias. You must use the full jQuery instead. Alternately, place your code using the $ shortcut inside a noConflict wrapper.

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
// $() will work as an alias for jQuery() inside of this function
[ your code goes here ]
} );
```

To insert your form structure, you can use add_shortcode() or simply use the visual editor. I will use a shortcode to handle the form response with php. You can see more details in the [shortcode api](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) pages.

Answer (score 0):

Step :1 Create Shortcode for the display purpose

```
function mycustomcode(){
    /*Place your code here*/
}
add_shortcode('mycustomcode','mycustomcode');
```

Step :2 open file where  you want to display just use this shortcode,

In php filecode,

```
do_shortcode('mycustomcode');
```

In WYSWYG (Wordpress Editor),

```
['mycustomcode']
```

Step :3

En queue you style and script

Answer (score 0):

To edit page, you should first figure out which template the page used.

You could refer the [WordPress Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) for more detail.

Or you could create a [page template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-templates/) for specific use, and assign the page template to the page at wp-admin.

If you still can't find the template to edit, there are plugins like [Show Current Template](https://wordpress.org/plugins/show-current-template/) and [Display Template Name](https://tw.wordpress.org/plugins/display-template-name/) to help you find it out.

Remember, when you are editing the template files, do it in the child theme.